# script error for scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which generates random numbers. I want the new No. generated to be added and the scroll bar should remain at the bottom so to keep an eye on the newly generated no. every time. But the scroll bar remain at its position where I Move it(can be at middle or top) and the new no. keep on generated and the scroll bar remain at its place.

```js
function fetchChat() { // 30% of chance of having new message
  if (Math.random() <= 0.3) {
    $("#messages").append("<div>" + "Random message " + Math.random() + "</div>");

    // Scroll to bottom if you are at bottom, with tolerance of 50px       if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
    scrollToBottom();
  }
}


function sendMessage(txt) {
  $("#messages").append("<div>" + txt + "</div>");
  scrollToBottom();
}

function scrollToBottom() {
  $(window).scrollTop(1e10); // Lazy hack
}

setInterval(function() {
  fetchChat();
}, 500);

$("#input").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    sendMessage($("#input").val());
    $("#input").val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<title>Live Table Data Edit</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <h3 align="center">You Are : Unknown</h3><br />
      <div id="live_data"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="messages" style="    border: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 250px;
        height: 210px;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
     "></div>
    <input id="input" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking this question consecutively for few days already, please check if this matched your requirement.

```js
function fetchChat() { // 30% of chance of having new message
    if (Math.random() <= 0.3) {
        $("#messages").append("<div>" + "Random message " + Math.random() + "</div>");
        scrollToBottom(); // Always scroll to bottom when new number arrived
    }
}

function sendMessage(txt) {
    $("#messages").append("<div>" + txt + "</div>");
    scrollToBottom();
}

function scrollToBottom() {
    $("#messages").scrollTop(1e10); // Lazy hack
}

setInterval(function() {
    fetchChat();
}, 500);

$("#input").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        sendMessage($("#input").val());
        $("#input").val("");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <h3 align="center">You Are: Unknown</h3><br/>
        <div id="live_data"></div>
    </div>  
    <div id="messages" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 250px; height: 210px; padding: 10px; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
    <input id="input" type="text"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: ya I have asked it yesterday.commented to ur answer but u didnt reply

Comment: That's mainly because insufficient requirements from your side, I am just trying my best to help

Comment: ok . U can tell me that in my previous question. Thanx for ur help.
can u tell me where I was wrong???

Comment: Can you let me know what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

write `$("#messages")` instead of `$(window)`

because you write `append text in #message div` not into `window`

```js
function fetchChat() { // 30% of chance of having new message
  if (Math.random() <= 0.3) {
    $("#messages").append("<div>" + "Random message " + Math.random() + "</div>");

    // Scroll to bottom if you are at bottom, with tolerance of 50px       if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
    scrollToBottom();
  }
}


function sendMessage(txt) {
  $("#messages").append("<div>" + txt + "</div>");
  scrollToBottom();
}

function scrollToBottom() {
  $("#messages").scrollTop(1e10); // Lazy hack
}

setInterval(function() {
  fetchChat();
}, 500);

$("#input").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    sendMessage($("#input").val());
    $("#input").val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<title>Live Table Data Edit</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <h3 align="center">You Are : Unknown</h3><br />
      <div id="live_data"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="messages" style="    border: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 250px;
        height: 210px;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
     "></div>
    <input id="input" type="text" />
```